# Access Infinite Dropdown Menu on Click instead of on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A while ago I searched for one of the many CSS infinite dropdown menus there's around the Internet but only one I found flexible and simple enough to be implemented by someone who doesn't go along with CSS:

```css
a, a:link, a:visited {
        color: #888 !important;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    /**
     * Infinitely nestable dropdown menu by @csswizardry
     * twitter.com/csswizardry
     *
     * Throw any `ul` or `ol` into horizontal mode, as per csswizardry.com/2011/09/the-nav-abstraction
     *
     * <ul class=nav>
     *   <li><a href=/>Home</a></li>
     *   <li><a href=/about>About</a></li>
     *   <li><a href=/portfolio>Portfolio</a></li>
     *   <li><a href=/contact>Contact</a></li>
     * </ul>
     */
    .nav {
        display: inline !important;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    
        .nav > li, .nav > li > a {
           display: inline;
           zoom: 1;
        }
    
            .nav li li a:hover {
                color: #B20000 !important;
            }
    
        /**
         * Create a vertically stacked nav by extending `.nav` with `.stacked`.
         *
         * <ul class="nav stacked">
         *   <li><a href=/>Home</a></li>
         *   <li><a href=/about>About</a></li>
         *   <li><a href=/portfolio>Portfolio</a></li>
         *   <li><a href=/contact>Contact</a></li>
         * </ul>
         */
        .stacked > li {
            display: list-item !important;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }
    
            .stacked > li > a {
                display: block;
            }
    
    /**
     * Flyouts are pieces of content that fly out of a parent when said parent is hovered.
     * They typically appear bottom-left of the parent.
     *
     * <div class=flyout>
     *   Foo
     *   <div class=flyout-content>
     *     <h1>Lorem</h1>
     *     <p>Ipsum</p>
     *   </div>
     * </div>
     */
    .flyout,
    .flyout-alt {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 0.4rem;
        position: relative;
    }
    
        .flyout-content {
            /* Position the flyouts off-screen. This is typically better than `display:none;`. */
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: -99999px;
    
            /**
             * Even though they are out of document flow, lots of nested flyouts can
             * eventually force scrollbars to appear as they become taller than the viewport.
             * We can undo this effect by giving them zero height.
             */
    
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
        /**
         * Bring the flyouts into view when you hover their parents.
         * Two different types of flyout; ‘regular’ (`.flyout`) and ‘alternative’ (`.flyout-alt`).
         */
        /* Regular flyouts sit all the way from the top, flush left. */
        .flyout:hover > .flyout-content {
            left: 0;
        }
    
        /* Alternative flyouts sit all the way from the left, flush top. */
        .flyout-alt:hover > .flyout-content {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
        }
    
        .flyout:hover > .flyout-content,
        .flyout-alt:hover > .flyout-content{
            /* Give the flyouts their height back once they come into view. */
            height: auto;
            overflow: visible;
        }
    
          .flyout.flyout-right:hover > .flyout-content,
          .flyout-alt.flyout-right:hover > .flyout-content{
              left: auto;
              right: 0;
          }
    
        /**
         * Site nav specific flyouts, an extension of `.flyout`.
         * Set up some styles to apply and persist when we hover things in the site nav.
         * This allows us to keep parents highlighted as we hover their contained flyouts [1].
         */
        .nav .flyout-content {
            /*background-color: #292b2c;*/
            background-color: #FFF;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            border: 1px solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, .15 );
            border-radius: .25rem;
            /*color: rgba( 255,255,255, .5 );*/
            color: #292b2c;
            font-size: 1rem;
            margin: .125rem 0 0;
            padding: .5rem 0;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
    
            .nav .flyout-content li {
                font-size: .9rem;
                padding: 0 0.8rem 0 1.2rem;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

        
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">

<h1 class="navbar-brand text-left">
      <a href="#">Brand</a>
    </h1>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
    
      <div class="navbar-nav">
    
        <ul class="nav">
    
          <li class="flyout">
    
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
              Group #1
            </a>
    
            <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
    
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  Entry #1
                </a>
              </li>
    
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  Entry #2
                </a>
              </li>
    
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  Entry #3
                </a>
              </li>
    
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  Entry #4
                </a>
              </li>
    
              <li class="flyout-alt">
    
                <a>
                  Sub-entry #1
                </a>
    
                <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
    
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      Sub-entry #2
                    </a>
                  </li>
    
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      Sub-entry #3
                    </a>
                  </li>
    
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      Sub-entry #4
                    </a>
                  </li>
    
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      Sub-entry #5
                    </a>
                  </li>
    
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      Sub-entry #6
                    </a>
                  </li>
    
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      Sub-entry #7
                    </a>
                  </li>
    
                </ul>
    
              </li>
    
            </ul>
    
          </li>
    
          <li class="flyout">
    
            <a class="dropdown-toggle">Group #2</a>
    
            <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
    
              <li>
                <a href="#">Entry #1</a>
              </li>
    
              <li>
                <a href="#">Entry #2</a>
              </li>
    
              <li>
                <a href="#">Entry #3</a>
              </li>
    
              <li>
                <a href="#">Entry #4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
    
          </li>
    
        </ul>
    
      </div>
    
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto pull-right hidden-sm-down" id="languages">
    
        <ul class="nav">
    
          <li class="flyout flyout-right">
    
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="/">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oPIkeF1.gif" alt="English" />
              English
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
            </a>       
    
            <ul class="flyout-content nav stacked">
    
              <li>
                
                <a href="/">
                
                  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/oPIkeF1.gif" alt="English" />
                  English
                </a>
              </li>
    
              <li>
                  <a href="/pt">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AnKluc7.gif" alt="Portuguese" />
                    Portuguese
                  </a>
                </li>
    
                <li>
                  <a href="/es">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4XI5r0w.gif" alt="Spanish" />
                    Spanish
                  </a>
                </li>
    
                <li>
                  <a href="/it">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/tSsnFZT.gif" alt="Italian" />
                    Italian
                  </a>
                </li>
    
            </ul>
    
          </li>
    
        </ul>
    
      </div>
    
    </div></nav>
```

> The inline editor is not working (again) so I made [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxd6e1L2/) as well.

If you hover the right menu a couple of times, where the issue is most noticeable, you'll, perhaps, feel how stressful is to target one of the little flags while the flyout is opened without letting it close.

I tried to workaround by increasing paddings and changing the positioning so the flyout content (white panel) gets closer to the element with the `:hover` but it's still resulting in a bad experience.

So, long story short, how could I fire these `:hover` on click, like in mobile?

I read about a hack with invisible checkboxes but I couldn't make it work.

I don't mind if jQuery is needed, it's already being used for other things anyway, but with pure CSS would be better as I'm trying to reduce the dependency preparing the site for AMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Group #1</a>`

`<a class="dropdown-toggle">Group #2</a>`

Add the `nav-link class` to the Group 2 link and things improve markedly.

Comment: Well, after adding the class you said to the **languages** menu where the problem was happening more noticeably, I saw it added a micro padding to the right and left. After that I was unable to reproduce the odd behavior but, why? Why this micro-padding (apparently) solves the issue?

Comment: When the mouse moves down from the main menu item to select a sub-menu item, if it exits the main menu item the popup goes away. The "micro padding" is there to ensure that there is no gap between the bottom of the main menu item and the top of the pop up. The sporadic behaviour you experienced was due to the speed with which the mouse moves. Slow - you get the issue, fast - you don't

Comment: Good Lord, I would never guess :o